# 502 Bad Gateway running ASP .NET Core 5 site on NGINX on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx

Not sure what the problem is:

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

**From nginx logs:**

```
2021/11/05 21:59:21 [error] 59385#59385: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5004/", host: "mdomain.com"
```

**My site nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com;
    }
}
```

**My ASP .NET core 5 site:**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5004");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem, I used a wildcard in the url in my ASP .NET project and it works.

webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5004");